# wordpress transfer error with bigdump

Tags: wordpress, dump, solution

Hello all I'm in the process of transferring my blog via big-dump due to its huge size of 30MB. However when transferring I get this error:

```
Error at the line 139: INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` VALUES (21620,13544,'akismet_as_submitted','a:67:{s:15:\"comment_post_ID\";s:4:\"6034\";s:14:\"comment_author\".....................continues..
```

I would like to know why this is occurring and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One can't be sure with the limited amount of information you have given, but I think the dump file was not uploaded or created properly. Probably, there is a file size limit for uploading on your new server.
Try to take a compressed database dump and importing.